# jQuery API architecture choices: why return single value instead of arrays for attr(), val(), ...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, architecture

I am curious about the reasoning behind some of jQuery API architecture choices.

**FROM THE DOCUMENTATION**

attr():

> Get the value of an attribute **for the first element** in the set of matched elements.

val():

> Get the current value of **the first element** in the set of matched elements.

Even if I have many objects:

```
$('div').val()
```

would only return the value of **the first element**.

**But SETTING works differently:**

val(value):

> Set the value of **each element in the set** of matched elements.

attr(attributeName, value):

> Set one or more attributes **for the set** of matched elements.

So my questions:

- Why decide that **getter operations** like val() should return only the first value instead of an array of values?
  (The user has to use a map operation if he wanted all of them in an array)
- Why not do the same with **setter operations** like .val(value)?
- I can see a use case (with `$('div').first()`) where we expect the call to val() to return the value (we know there is only one dom element in the matched set) instead of an array of length 1. But why not handle it with a concept of a "single dom element query object" (that only gets created after calls to methods like first() or eq())?

Comment: Modify or create custom methods that fulfill requirements utilizing `$.fn.extend`, or modifying the source itself ?

Comment: I don't have such requirements, just curious why such a decision was made when it seems counter-intuitive to me to have different behavior for getters and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: I do not take part in the jquery development, so these thoughts may be entirely off the actual design decisions.

Anyway, imho your proposal does not seem to offer any advantage:

1. to process an array of data gleaned from the elements of a jquery collection the user would have to iterate over this array anyway - this can be done using jquery's `each` method in the first place which has the additional benefit of immediate access to the element carrying the attribute:

   `$("my_spiffy_selector").each( function ( idx, e ) {
       $(e).attr("blarf").whatever();
   });`
2. Otoh it would complicate matters (at least the jquery code base), if the getters return type would be polymorphic or if there were different getters.
3. The arguably most common use case would entail at least an additional `.first()` call.

Comment: (1) is only true if you do need a each loop yourself. Often, you don't or rely on existing operators, e.g you could doMath.min($(".blabla".attr("price")). Also this point could also apply to setters but somehow the API decision was different there.
(2) is a very valid concern. (3) Why do you say the most common use case? If I KNOW for certain (I called first() or eq()) there is only one element, I expect 1 result and not an array. If I have many objects, why should I want to only get the first val()? I would say my most common use case is to actually call map() as this is what I want.

Comment: ad (1) the situation for setters is different: here you distribute _identical values_ to a number of elements. the looping argument seems valid, though in many cases you'd still have to do some conversions as the attr values are returned as strings (eg. your min price detection will fail on `['100','99']`). ad (3) point taken. i can't be sure of course. however, bulk processing of data stored in the dom using javascript sounds like a suboptimal choice to me, i'd expect xslt or comparable technology to be better suited in most cases (i'm aware of the fact that you can't always choose freely).

Comment: re (1) and (3), my example was poorly chosen. Think about collecting values for jQuery methods like width(), height(), offset(), position(), scrollLeft(), ... I am unclear why it only returns the value for the first element and not an array of all width, height, offset, ... for all elements.

Comment: while i see valid scenarios for your latter examples, i still doubt that these data will be bulk-processed frequently (eg. i'd rather expect positional data to be processed for a single container widget instead, the respective attributes on descendants being defined relative to this container). this is just guesswork, of course, i have no hard statistics on that.